# Compare when value could be both NULL or text

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Now I know you can't directly compare NULL to anything (as null is unknown) so how would I achieve the following:

```
select  *
    from    Material as m
    where   MtrlCode = 826 and
            Exposlimit <> 'compareMe'
```

Where Exposlimit MAY be NULL or it may not be.
'compareMe' may also be NULL.

Therefore how do I compare the two?  Both sides could be either text or NULL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select  * 
from    Material as m 
where   MtrlCode = 826 
    and (Exposlimit <> 'compareMe'
         or (Exposlimit is null and compareme is not null) 
         or (Exposlimi is not null and compareme is null))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use IFNULL function for such cases.

i.e.

WHERE IFNULL(FieldA, 'MagicConstant') = IFNULL(FieldB, 'MagicConstant')

Comment: Does IFNULL exist in T-SQL? Even if you use ISNULL, the optimizer will struggle to use any indexes you may have defined.

Comment: @Paul, yes sql-server have not function-based indexes, and workaround (http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/T-SQL+Aids/31906/) look very ugly.

Answer (score 1):

```
select  *
    from    Material as m
    where   (MtrlCode = 826 or MtrlCode IS NULL)  and
            (Exposlimit <> 'compareMe' or Exposlimit IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider that it is easier to find equality:

```
(Column = @Value or (Column is null and @Value is null))
```

Which results in true when both values are equal.
We would ideally be able to negate this statement to find inequality, but the tri-state logic of SQL breaks that idea, as `NOT(UNKNOWN) = UNKNOWN`

```
--DO NOT USE, broken
NOT (Column = @Value or (Column is null and @Value is null))
```

Therefore, if we check for only the `TRUE` value, and negate it, we still end up with a readable operation.

```
CASE WHEN Column is null and @Value is null or Column = @Value THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
select  *
    from    Material as m
    where   MtrlCode = 826 and
            Exposlimit IS NOT NULL AND 'compareMe' IS NOT NULL AND Exposlimit <> 'compareMe'
```